# Android : Button gravity set programmatically not working

Tags: android, button, gravity

I can't set the text gravity of a Button dynamically.

My button is in a `LinearLayout`, with a vertical orientation.

When I create a button in the xml file, everything works as expected :

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:text="My button"/>
```

But when I create the same button dinamically, text remains centered instead of being left aligned:

```
Button myButton = new Button(context);
myButton.setText("My button");
myLinearLayout.addView(myButton);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) myButton.getLayoutParams();
params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
params.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.START;
```

Do you have any idea why the text remains centered when I create my button programmatically?
For your information, I need to be in API 16 (so myButton.setTextAlignment() won't work).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: DO a requestLayout on the parent view.  You changed the layout params, but you need to tell the parent to recalculate its children's positions/sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code above as follows and let me know which of them works:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.START;

Button myButton = new Button(context);
myButton.setText("My button");
myButton.setLayoutParams(params);

myLinearLayout.addView(myButton);
```

**OR**

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.START;

Button myButton = new Button(context);
myButton.setText("My button");

myLinearLayout.addView(myButton, params);
```

**OR**

```
Button myButton = new Button(context);
myButton.setText("My button");
myButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.START);
myLinearLayout.addView(myButton);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but for some reason, the text is still centered...

Comment: @thenaoh I updated the question with a second option.. could you try also?

Comment: Thanks, but still not working. But if I replace the Button by a TextView, it works as expected....

Comment: @thenaoh Updated again :)

Comment: Oh my... yes!! Last option works for me!! I totally forgot it, my bad ;-) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @thenaoh Great! I'm glad I could help you. I kindly request to mark the answer as accepted, if possible. Best Regards